# Why clearInterval is not stopping setInterval?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a Timer for a project that record audios and while on the making, I've faced with this problem: setInterval is not stopping, why?

I have the following code:

---

```
/** Audio **/
var timerseconds = 0;
$('.audio-recorder-dialog-con').on('click', '#record', function() {
    gotrecordval = document.getElementById("record").value;

    //Crónometro
    var timerseconds = setInterval(function() {
        rseconds = parseInt(document.getElementById("r-seconds").value);
        if (rseconds == 59) {
            document.getElementById("r-seconds").value = "00";
        }
        rseconds = parseInt(document.getElementById("r-seconds").value);
        rseconds += 1;
        if (rseconds < 10) {
            document.getElementById("r-seconds").value = ("00" + rseconds).substr(-2);
        }
        if (rseconds >= 10) {
            document.getElementById("r-seconds").value = rseconds;
        }
    }, 1000);
    //

    if (gotrecordval == "Empezar a Grabar Audio") {
        document.getElementById("record").value = "Detener/Subir";
    }

    if (gotrecordval == "Detener/Subir") {
        document.getElementById("record").value = "Empezar a Grabar Audio";
        $('.audio-recorder-dialog-con').fadeOut(500);
        $(".contenido-dialog-new-d").fadeIn(500);
        $("#aviaudio").fadeIn(500);
        clearInterval(timerseconds);
    }

});
```

--FIXED--

I've fixed it by adding this inside the setInterval:

```
//Crónometro
var timerseconds = setInterval(function(){
rseconds = parseInt(document.getElementById("r-seconds").value);
if(rseconds==59){document.getElementById("r-seconds").value = "00";}
rseconds = parseInt(document.getElementById("r-seconds").value);
rseconds+=1;
if(rseconds<10){document.getElementById("r-seconds").value = ("00" + rseconds).substr(-2);}
if(rseconds>=10){document.getElementById("r-seconds").value = rseconds;}

--Code added-
$('html, body').on('click', '.open-audio', function(){
clearInterval(timerseconds);
});
--

}, 1000);

//
```

".open-audio" is an image that opens the recording dialog for the user, so when you re-open it, the clearInterval works.

Comment: You scoped `timerseconds` to the `click` handler because of its `var` declaration, and the `clearInterval` is behind a condition of the `if` statement, so you'll want to check that. Beyond that, indenting your code makes it much easer to read and debug.

Comment: If the interval starts on one click, and you intend to stop it on the next click, it won't work, as you've just overwritten `timerseconds` with a new interval, and the reference to the old interval was lost, and now it can't be stopped.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you added to your question is not sound: this will create a new event handler at every 'tick' of the `setInterval` timer. That is not the right way to do it.

Instead, only execute `setInterval` in the case you need to start it, so put it inside the first `if`:

```
if (gotrecordval == "Empezar a Grabar Audio") {
    //Crónometro
    var timerseconds = setInterval(function() {
        rseconds = parseInt(document.getElementById("r-seconds").value);
        if (rseconds == 59) {
            document.getElementById("r-seconds").value = "00";
        }
        rseconds = parseInt(document.getElementById("r-seconds").value);
        rseconds += 1;
        if (rseconds < 10) {
            document.getElementById("r-seconds").value = ("00" + rseconds).substr(-2);
        }
        if (rseconds >= 10) {
            document.getElementById("r-seconds").value = rseconds;
        }
    }, 1000);
    //
    document.getElementById("record").value = "Detener/Subir";
}
```